# Give a minimum sized structure such that this sentence is invalid.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

part of my propositional calculus homework is to answer the following question:

> Give a minimum size structure which shows that the following sentence
> is not valid.
>
> $\forall x \forall y \forall z((x < y ∧ y < z) ⊃ x < z)$

My first question is that how could this sentence possibly be invalid? I mean surely given the antecedent the consequent must hold. I'm thinking of the naturals and reals for universes but this sentence always holds. Second, what does a minimum sized structure mean?

Can somebody help me come up with a model such that the sentence is invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimum-sized is asking you to find a structure with the smallest possible number of elements in which the sentence is not valid. Just because the relation is given the name $<$ doesn't mean that it has to have the usual properties of an ordering relation. Take a model with 2 elements $a$ and $b$ say and define $x < y$ to hold iff $x \neq y$. Then $a < b$ and $b < a$, but $\lnot a < a$. I'll leave it to you to show that the sentence holds for any binary relation on a singleton set (there are only two such relations to check) (and hence that 2 is the minimum size).

Comment: So what you're saying is we can simply define $x < y$ is be something else other than the meaning that $x$ is less than $y$?

Comment: Yes! That's exactly right.

Comment: For the last sentence in your answer, you say that we need to show that the sentence holds for any binary relation on a singleton set. First, aren't we trying to show that the sentence doesn't hold? Second, does a singleton set mean a set with only one element in it?

Comment: Yes, a singleton set is one with only one element. We need to show that 2 is the minimum number of elements we can get away with: so we need to show that the sentence holds in any structure with only one element.

Comment: I see, so the sentence holds for any structure with a singleton universe, but for any structure with a universe of 2 elements, then any binary relationship definition we give to $x < y$, the sentence is invalid. The only binary relations I can think of are $x > y$, $x = y$, and $x < y$. However, aren't there an infinite number of definitions I could give to $x < y$?

Comment: No. It is not true that the sentence is invalid for any binary relationship on a set with two elements, e.g., consider the usual definition of < on $\{1, 2\}$. There are only finitely many binary relations on a finite set. (If the set has $n$ elements there are $2^{n^2}$ different binary relations on it.)

Comment: I now understand the answer you provided. Thank you for taking the time to clarify.